# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "[знак или слово]": syntax error

Tags: python, sqlite

Хочу запустить елементарнейший код

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('base.db-journal')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (id INT, name TEXT, group TEXT, TgID TEXT)')
```

Имею такую ошибку: sqlite3.OperationalError: near "group": syntax error

Замена имен, использование форматирования, ничего не помогает. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

Слово `group` является [зарезервированным](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) в `SQLite`. Задайте другое имя для поля и ошибка пропадёт.

Comment: Спасибо. Раньше не помогало, но после вашего комментария помогло. Теперь все выполняется но открыв в DB Browser for SQLite не вижу созданной таблицы.

Comment: @МихаилПолещук, попробуйте для начала добавить туда что-нибудь. Если что, лучше задать новый вопрос с новой проблемой.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь